# How do I create FFI bindings to C functions expecting OR-ed bytes?

Tags: rust, ffi

I tried to create FFI bindings to [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.1.4/modbus_set_error_recovery.html), written in C.
Here I stumble upon this [function](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/blob/master/tests/unit-test-client.c#L97)

```
modbus_set_error_recovery(ctx,
                          MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK |
                          MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL);
```

The second parameter is defined as

```
typedef enum
{
    MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_NONE          = 0,
    MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK          = (1<<1),
    MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL      = (1<<2)
} modbus_error_recovery_mode;
```

My `bindgen`-generated bindings are these:

```
#[repr(u32)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub enum modbus_error_recovery_mode {
    MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_NONE = 0,
    MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK = 2,
    MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL = 4,
}
```

and

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn modbus_set_error_recovery(ctx: *mut modbus_t,
                                     error_recovery:
                                         modbus_error_recovery_mode)
     -> ::std::os::raw::c_int;
}
```

My safe interface looks like this, so far:

```
pub fn set_error_recovery(&mut self, error_recovery_mode: ErrorRecoveryMode) -> Result<()> {

    unsafe {
        match ffi::modbus_set_error_recovery(self.ctx, error_recovery_mode.to_c()) {
            -1 => bail!(Error::last_os_error()),
            0 => Ok(()),
            _ => panic!("libmodbus API incompatible response"),
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
use std::ops::BitOr;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum ErrorRecoveryMode {
    NONE = 0,
    Link = 2,
    Protocol = 4,
}

impl ErrorRecoveryMode {
    pub fn to_c(self) -> ffi::modbus_error_recovery_mode {
        match self {
            NONE => ffi::modbus_error_recovery_mode::MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_NONE,
            Link => ffi::modbus_error_recovery_mode::MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK,
            Protocol => ffi::modbus_error_recovery_mode::MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL,
        }
    }
}

impl BitOr for ErrorRecoveryMode {
    type Output = Self;
    fn bitor(self, rhs: ErrorRecoveryMode) -> ErrorRecoveryMode {
        self | rhs
    }
}
```

This triggered a stack overflow if I call `set_error_recovery` like this

```
assert!(modbus.set_error_recovery(ErrorRecoveryMode::Link | ErrorRecoveryMode::Protocol).is_ok())
```

The error is

```
thread 'set_error_recovery' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that C's `enum` and Rust's `enum` are **very** different things.  In particular, C allows an `enum` to have absolutely any value whatsoever, whether or not that value corresponds to a variant.

Rust does not.  Rust *relies* on `enum`s only ever having a single value of a defined variant, or you run the risk of undefined behaviour.

What you have is not an enumeration (in the Rust sense), you have are bit flags, for which you want the [`bitflags`](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) crate.

As for the stack overflow, that's just because you defined the `BitOr` implementations in terms of itself; that code is unconditionally recursive.

Answer (score 4):

As DK. mentioned:

- C's `enum` and Rust's `enum` have different restrictions.
- It's not valid to have a Rust enum that isn't one of the enum variants.
- What you have is called "bitflags"

Luckily, Bindgen understands bitflags. If you generate your headers while passing the `bitfield-enum` flag or by using [`Builder::bitfield_enum`](https://docs.rs/bindgen/0.30.0/bindgen/struct.Builder.html#method.bitfield_enum):

```
bindgen --bitfield-enum modbus_error_recovery_mode fake-modbus.h
```

Bindgen will generate constants for each C enum value, a newtype wrapper, and implementations of the `Bit*` traits:

```
// Many implementation details removed 

pub struct modbus_error_recovery_mode(pub ::std::os::raw::c_uint);

pub const modbus_error_recovery_mode_MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_NONE: modbus_error_recovery_mode =
    modbus_error_recovery_mode(0);    
pub const modbus_error_recovery_mode_MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK: modbus_error_recovery_mode =
    modbus_error_recovery_mode(2);
pub const modbus_error_recovery_mode_MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL: modbus_error_recovery_mode =
    modbus_error_recovery_mode(4);

impl ::std::ops::BitOr<modbus_error_recovery_mode> for modbus_error_recovery_mode {}
impl ::std::ops::BitOrAssign for modbus_error_recovery_mode {}
impl ::std::ops::BitAnd<modbus_error_recovery_mode> for modbus_error_recovery_mode {} 
impl ::std::ops::BitAndAssign for modbus_error_recovery_mode {}

extern "C" {
    pub fn modbus_set_error_recovery(
        ctx: *mut modbus_t,
        error_recovery: modbus_error_recovery_mode,
    ) -> ::std::os::raw::c_int;
}
```

---

> How do I expose the bindgen generated constants to the public

Of course, creating an idiomatic Rust API to non-Rust code is the hard part. I might try something like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Modbus(*mut raw::modbus_t);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
enum ErrorRecovery {
    Link,
    Protocol,
}

impl ErrorRecovery {
    fn as_raw(&self) -> raw::modbus_error_recovery_mode {
        use ErrorRecovery::*;

        match *self {
            Link => raw::modbus_error_recovery_mode_MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK,
            Protocol => raw::modbus_error_recovery_mode_MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL,
        }
    }
}

impl Modbus {
    fn set_error_recovery(&mut self, flags: Option<&[ErrorRecovery]>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let flag = flags.unwrap_or(&[]).iter().fold(
            raw::modbus_error_recovery_mode_MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_NONE,
            |acc, v| acc | v.as_raw(),
        );

        let res = unsafe { raw::modbus_set_error_recovery(self.0, flag) };
        Ok(()) // real error checking
    }
}
```